# Phonegap 3 ios project is called "HelloWorld". How can I change it?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have created a new Phonegap 3 project. When I run:

> phonegap build ios

An XCode project is created named "HelloWorld". How can I change this project name? Should I do it manually or is there a command integrated in PhoneGap to setup everything right at the project creation? I am trying to avoid as many manual steps as possible.

Comment: Please explain the "-1". I would appreciate any tip to improve the clarity of the question. Thank you.

Comment: please take a look http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/rename_app

Comment: Open Project Navigator select Current Prject Name Then Your right side
 File Inspector >> Identity >> Project Name Change And Click Validate Setting bottom button

Comment: When you create the project using the Phonegap 3 CLI, you are meant to change the name from HelloWorld to something more appropriate. It says this in the document which tells you to run that command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was:

> phonegap create path/to/my-app --id "com.example.app" --name "My App"

Comment: This is creating a new project, you can change this values even after the project is created.

Comment: @givanse How? When I change config.xml, command "phonegap build ios" will result in xcodebuild: error: Unable to read project 'MyProject.xcodeproj'. Is there a command for renaming already existing phonegap project?

Comment: If you remove the ios platform from the project `cordova platform remove ios` and then add it back `cordova platform add ios`, the project should then compile correctly. The following link is related to Ionic Framework, but the underlying mechanism is the same: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-app-name-in-config-xml-with-spaces/30166

Answer (score 9):

If you want to change an existing project:

1. Edit the file ./.cordova/config.json Change the "name" field to your new project name.
2. Edit the file ./www/config.xml Change the "name" field to your new project name.
3. Make a copy of your ./platforms/ios directory (optional, only needed if you have modified the ios code directly)
4. Remove the ./platforms/ios directory.
5. Run "phonegap run ios"

This will create a new project with the correct name.

Answer (score 6):

Change the config.xml from the main www directory

```
 <name>Here is the Name you want to change </name>
    <description>
        here is description of your application
    </description>
 <author email="youremail@example.com" href="http://yoursite.com">
       My team
 </author>
```

Now rebuild app with CLI

```
phonegap build ios 
phonegap install ios
```

OR

```
phonegap run ios
```

Comment: In 3.5.0 these steps result in an error - renamed project file cannot be parsed.

Answer (score 3):

Open up your project >> From top menu "Project" >> "Edit Active Target
" >> Under "Packaging" you'll see "Product Name".

Comment: +1 cordova rename did not work with a space in the app name, changing product name in the xcode project just did the job

Answer (score 2):

Edit `www/config.xml`:

```
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "your.app.id"
        version   = "1.0.0">
    <name>Here is the Name you want to change </name>
    <description>
        here is description of your application
    </description>
    <author email="youremail@example.com" href="http://yoursite.com">
        My team
    </author>
```

Update and rebuild:

```
phonegap platform update ios
phonegap run ios
```

Comment: It does not work in 3.5.0. Changing the project name results in an error.

Comment: Sounds bad, Phonegap/Cordova should add traces/logs, what were they thinking!

Answer (score 0):

From the `PhoneGap` [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html):

```
Launch Terminal.app

Drag the copied bin folder to the Terminal.app icon in your Dock, it should launch a new Terminal window
Type in ./create <project_folder_path> <package_name> <project_name> then press "Enter"
```

Comment: This is phonegap 2.0.

Comment: My apologies. I take it the procedure has changed?

Comment: The development workflow has completely changed and it's not very well documented.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode: Select project - Under tab Info - Custom iOS Target - Bundle display name - edit the name